# How to train and deploy model in script mode on Sagemaker without using jupyter notebook instance (serverless)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have been using a jupyter notebook instance to spin up a training job (on separate instance) and deploy the endpoint (on another instance). I am using sagemaker tensorflow APIs for this as shown below:

```
# create Tensorflow object and provide and entry point script
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='tf-train.py', role='SageMakerRole',
                      train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type='ml.p2.xlarge',
                      framework_version='1.12', py_version='py3')

# train model on data on s3 and save model artifacts to s3
tf_estimator.fit('s3://bucket/path/to/training/data')

# deploy model on another instance using checkpoints saved on S3
predictor = estimator.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                         instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge',
                         endpoint_type='tensorflow-serving')
```

I have been doing all of these steps through a jupyter notebook instance. What AWS services I can use to get rid off the dependency of jupyter notebook instance and automate these tasks of training and deploying the model in serverless fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend `AWS Step Functions`.  Been using it to schedule `SageMaker Batch Transform` and preprocessing jobs since it integrates with `CloudWatch` event rules.  It can also train models, perform hpo tuning, and integrates with `lambda`.  There is a SageMaker/Step Functions SDK as well as you can use Step Functions directly by creating state machines. Some examples and documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/introducing-aws-step-functions-data-science-sdk-amazon-sagemaker/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sagemaker.html

Comment: Will this still be creating/using/triggering the endpoint of the model on SageMaker? Or only using batch jobs?